# Declare a template function as friend

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, friend

I have a global function like this:

```
namespace X
{
namespace Y
{
template <R, ...T>
R foo(T&&... args)
{
    R r(args...);
    return r;
}
}
}
```

Then in another class `A`, I want to declare this function `foo` as friend of `A`. So I did:

```
class A
{
template <R, ...T>
friend R X::Y::foo(T&&... args);
A(int x, int y){}
};
```

Now when, I call `X::Y::foo<A>(4, 5)` it fails to compile with error that foo can not access the private constructor of `A`. I am unable to understand the error, how do I declare the `foo` as friend of `A` correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this the real code?

Comment: Try `friend R X::Y::foo<R, T...>(T&&...);`.

Comment: This was a bug in Visual Studio 2012 CTP, reported it to Microsoft. They have already fixed it internally.

Answer (score 2):

After fixing the syntactic issues with template parameters and parameter packs, this seems to work:

```
namespace X
{
    namespace Y
    {
        template <typename R, typename ...T>
        R foo(T&&... args)
        {
            R r(args...);
            return r;
        }
    }
}

class A
{
    template <typename R, typename ...T>
    friend R X::Y::foo(T&&... args);
    A(int x, int y){}
};

int main()
{
    X::Y::foo<A>(1, 2);
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://ideone.com/RHt3f3) of the above code compiling.